# Multiple selection listview with two textviews

Tags: android, android-listview, multipleselection

Is't possible to use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` default format to make listview with two textview inside? i want to make a multiple selection listview in a simplest way.

Like this

Item| checkbox
sub item|